# Excel Styles.IndentLevel-> Runtime Error 94: Invalid use of Null

Tags: vba, excel

### Description

Checking the uninitiated `.IndentLevel` of a Style throws the **Runtime Error 94: Invalid use of Null**.

> If ThisWorkbook.Styles(1).IndentLevel then

Checking if the uninitiated `.IndentLevel` of a Style `IsNull` or `IsError` also throws the **Runtime Error 94: Invalid use of Null**.

> If IsNull(ThisWorkbook.Styles(1).IndentLevel) then
>   If IsError(ThisWorkbook.Styles(1).IndentLevel) then

[image]

### Work Around

```
On Error Resume Next

Call IsNull(ThisWorkbook.Styles(1).IndentLevel)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

### Test Code

```
Sub TestIndent()
    With ThisWorkbook.Styles.Add("Test - IndentLevel")
        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print .IndentLevel
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error - .IndentLevel:"; .Err.Number, Err.Description
        Err.Clear

        Debug.Print IsNull(.IndentLevel)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error - IsNull(.IndentLevel):"; Err.Number, Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0

        .IndentLevel = 1

        Debug.Print "No Error - .IndentLevel:"; .IndentLevel
        Debug.Print "No Error - IsNull(.IndentLevel)"; IsNull(.IndentLevel)

        .Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

### Actual Question

Is this an unhandled `Invalid Use Null` error inside the `Style.IndentLevel` property itself?

Comment: It works if `Style` object is assigned first to a variable, declared as `Variant` or `Object`, and after that `.IndentLevel` property of style the variable referencing to accessed. If variable is declared as `Style` then the same error occurs. Seems that is something in Style interface implementation.